# Printing to php integrated server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm running Laravel 4 with PHP integrated server:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

It's there a way to log information into php integrated server instead of writing to the logs with `Log::info()` (as a way to customize the output), such as other web frameworks? Echoing doesn't seems to work either.

Sometimes I just need quick information about something, and having to check the logs or printing to html doesn't seems optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php 5.4 builtin server is not a PHP process per se, so you cannot output stuff in the terminal like `echo 'hello terminal'`. This mean the server cannot run code for you the way you described. It is just for serving PHP apps from a dir.

I'll guess you try to get the same functionality as eg. python server where you can print something to the terminal. As far as i know the only way to have PHP print stuff in the terminal is by creating a cli app/script and running it `php script.php --optional --flags`

My suggestion is just to print_r/var_dump stuff to your view (or keep reading log files), and for more complex debugging use xdebug.